# Cannot find cloned python arcgispro-py3 environment with conda env list

Tags: python, arcpy, anaconda, conda

I am trying to clone my python environment that comes with ArcGIS Pro (arcgispro-py3 located in C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3) to a location I can access (I do not have administrative privileges). I followed these instructions from ESRI https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000020560 but gave a direct path name for the clone (C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3_clone).

When I cloned arcgispro-py3, I did so within my Python Command prompt. The cloned environment shows up when I list out my environments in the Python Command prompt with `conda env list`. However, when I do so from the Anaconda prompt, the environment is not shown (only base shows). I can, however, activate it using the path to the cloned environment. (Though oddly when I run `conda env list` again from the cloned environment, it has no output.)

I had used this same workflow on a different computer previously and had no problems. My main question is why can I not see all of the environments with `conda env list`? The only thing that I can think of is that I also installed Anaconda (even though conda comes with ArcGIS Pro). I don't know if that confused anything.

Comment: Have you tried adding the path to ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs to the condarc config file? You need to add the path before creating the environment and then, when you create a new environment in that location, you should be able to activate it using only the name. Also, its name should appear along with the path when you run "conda env list". https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/configuration/use-condarc.html

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Unfortunately I do not have read/write access to the .condarc config file. I eventually uninstalled Pro and then reinstalled for a single user (this defaults to AppData instead of Program Files). I was able to clone from this location.

Comment: @ENIAC-6 you have write access to .condarc. If it doesn't exist already, create it in `%userprofile%\.condarc` e.g. `C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\.condarc` or use the `conda config` command.

Comment: It's ridiculous that I had to find this question to understand where this damn `arcgispro-py3` environment was located. arcpy docs are seriously lacking.

Answer (score 0):

I also did not have the `arcgispro-py3` env in my python command prompt nor my conda command prompt.

Here are my steps from using AliWieckowicz and user2856 comments

1. Open conda prompt and view .condarc file

   - Find the `envs_dirs:` tag

```
conda config --show
```

[image]

2. We need to add the ArcPro env path

   - Mine is located here: `C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs`

```
conda config --add envs_dirs "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs"
```

3. View the new changes in the .condarc file

```
conda config --show
```

[image]

4. List conda envs

```
conda env list
```

[image]